# WSO2 IS 5.2.0 : CXF based JAX-RS Client in a custom PIP not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement a PIP extension for WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0, which uses a CXF baseed JAX-RS client. Unfortunately I am still getting ClassNotFound Exception, e.g.:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient cannot be found by com.example.wso2.pip_1.0.0_1.0.0
```

In my understanding the CXF runtime einvironment is loaded through the definition in "webapp-classloading.xml".  Am I missing s.th.?

Comment: you need to provide much more information to get any reasonable answer. The runtime classes are loaded using the OSGi import statement.  Did you create a proper OSGi bundle? What is your import statement? start the wso2is with the console (-DosgiConsole), you can check what class references are not resolved (please google for that). The best start-up is to follow the tutoria VERY closely and understand each detail :(

Comment: The bundle is created dynamically by WSO2 and has a wildcard DynamicImport statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is for sure not the best solution, I ended up putting the CXF dependecies into the PIP bundle itself.

My hope was that this is not necessary. My code runs now, but appreciate if someone is able to point me to the preferred solution without having the CXF jars in the bundle.